# Excel worksheet crashes on Page Setup and Print Preview

Tags: excel-2013

Excel 2013, 32 and 64 bit, Windows 7.

An Excel worksheet "AuditProgram" (NOT WORKBOOK) crashes when I run the "Page Setup" and the "Print Preview" dialog boxes.  If I run these dialog boxes, while on this worksheet, it works fine.  But when I go to run a macro that pulls up a form, it crashes.  The macro works just fine if I never open the two dialog boxes.  The file will also crash on Save after running the macro then the two print dialog boxes.

How can a dialog box corrupt a worksheet?

If I hide the rows, it never crashes on the macro or Save.  If I add the macro to the quick access toolbar and click it from there, it crashes on the second round.  If I run the macro from the "Macros" menu it crashes on the 8th round.  It crashes much less.  All the other worksheets work fine and do not crash even if I run the dialog boxes or macro, on those worksheets.  But I go back to the AuditProgram worksheet and it crashes on the macro?  This doesn't make any sense to me. There is something related to a memory leak, print preview/page setup, and the way Excel views this specific worksheet.

**NOTE: when it crashes on the macro, it crashes immediately.  I don't even see the form MMDia come up.  So it only runs like 4 lines of code before it crashes.  It's so weird!**

**NOTE: on form MMDia that option C is picked... MMOpt_V = "C"**

**NOTE: on form PrtDia that option PrtAPBtn is clicked... Range("PrtOpt") = AP**

Macro:

```
Sub MainMenu()
Application.Run "MM"
End Sub

Private Sub MM()
Dim MMOpt_V As String
Dim Prt_V As String
Range("MMSel").ClearContents
Range("MMOpt").ClearContents
MMDia.Show
MMOpt_V = Range("MMOpt").Value
Range("MMSel").ClearContents
Range("MMOpt").ClearContents
If MMOpt_V = "A" Then
    Application.Run "Headings"
End If
If MMOpt_V = "B" Then
    Application.Run "AdPrgHide"
    Application.Run "CklstHide"
End If
If MMOpt_V = "C" Then
    PrtDia.Show
    Prt_V = Range("PrtOpt").Value
    Range("PrtOpt").ClearContents
    If Prt_V = "Ques" Then
        Application.Run "PrtQues"
    ElseIf Prt_V = "AP" Then
        Application.Run "PrtAP"
    ElseIf Prt_V = "Cklst" Then
        Application.Run "PrtCklst"
    Else
        End
    End If
End If
If MMOpt_V = "D" Then
    Application.Run "SUMacLib.xlsm!Templates"
End If
End Sub

Private Sub PrtAP()
    Application.Goto reference:="Ques1"
    Application.Goto reference:="AuditProgram!R1C1"
    Application.Goto reference:="APLineRef1"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveCell.Offset(6, 0).Select
    CHDR = Worksheets("Headings").Range("APCHdr").Value
    WkshtNM = Worksheets("Headings").Range("APWkshtNm").Value
    CFTR = Worksheets("Headings").Range("TxTypName").Value
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AuditProgram").PageSetup
        .PrintTitleColumns = ""
        .PrintTitleRows = "APPrtRow"
        .CenterHeader = "&""Arial,Bold""&12" & CHDR & Chr(10) & WkshtNM & ""
        .LeftHeader = ""
        .RightHeader = "&""Arial,Normal""&10" & "Page &P of &N"
        .CenterFooter = "&""Arial,Normal""&10" & CFTR
        .PrintArea = "PrtRangeAP"
        .Zoom = 85
    End With
    Application.Run "SUMacLib.xlsm!Prt_Port"
End Sub

Private Sub Prt_Port()
With Worksheets("AuditProgram").PageSetup
    .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(1.75)
    .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
    .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
    .Orientation = xlPortrait
End With
Application.Run "SUMacLib.xlsm!Prt_Doc"
End Sub

Private Sub Prt_Doc()
With Worksheets("AuditProgram").PageSetup
    .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = False
    .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
    .LeftFooter = ""
    .RightFooter = ""
    .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
    .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
    .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
    .PrintHeadings = False
    .PrintGridlines = False
    .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
    .CenterHorizontally = True
    .CenterVertically = False
    .Draft = False
    .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
    .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
    .Order = xlOverThenDown
    .BlackAndWhite = False
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Goto reference:="APLineRef1"
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPageSetup).Show
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrintPreview).Show
End Sub
```

Form MMDia:

```
Private Sub MMCancelBtn_Click()
Range("MMSel").ClearContents
Range("MMOpt").ClearContents
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub MMLst_Change()
Application.EnableEvents = False
Range("MMSel").Value = MMLst.Text
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub MMLst_Click()
Range("MMSel").Value = MMLst.Text
End Sub

Private Sub MMOkBtn_Click()
Range("MMOpt").FormulaR1C1 = "=left(MMSel,1)"
Unload Me
End Sub
```

Form PrtDia:

```
Private Sub PrtAPBtn_Click()
Range("PrtOpt").Value = "AP"
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub PrtCancelBtn_Click()
Range("PrtOpt").Value = "Stop"
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub PrtCklstBtn_Click()
Range("PrtOpt").Value = "Cklst"
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub PrtQuesBtn_Click()
Range("PrtOpt").Value = "Ques"
Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Update...So when I hide most of the rows in the worksheet, it stops crashing.

Comment: It would be helpful to post the macro, or at least the germane parts if it is a large one.

Comment: I did post the macro, but it appears to not be related to the issue.  I will edit and include it back in.